# Trying to find records between two dates on one table and some information on another

Tags: sql

I am trying to combine these two queries not sure exactly how though. I think I need to use a inner or a left join maybe but not sure the syntax for that.

```
SELECT job_ID, SUM(AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS), SUM(Record_count)
FROM job_step js
GROUP BY js.JOB_ID;

SELECT job_id,start_dts FROM job
WHERE start_dts BETWEEN '27-JAN-04' AND '17-MAR-05';
```

Comment: Are `AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS` and `Record_count` columns in `job_step`?

Comment: yes they are in job_step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT js.job_ID, j.start_dts, SUM(js.AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS), SUM(js.Record_count)
FROM job_step js
LEFT JOIN job j ON j.job_id = js.job_ID
GROUP BY js.JOB_ID, j.start_dts
WHERE j.start_dts BETWEEN '27-JAN-04' AND '17-MAR-05';
```

Comment: Just a head's up, but the `outer join` here is being negated by the `where` criteria...

Comment: Ah, I see -- so `inner join` here is more precise

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Thowing a "SQL command not properly ended"

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you want:

```
SELECT j.job_id, MIN(j.start_dts) as start_dts,
       SUM(js.AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS), SUM(js.Record_count)
FROM job j JOIN
     job_step js
WHERE j.start_dts BETWEEN DATE '2004-01-27' AND DATE '2005-03-17'
GROUP BY j.job_id;
```

Notes:

- The assumption is that  you want all jobs in the specified range, which is why it is the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.
- I am guessing that you are using Oracle (based on the date format).  The `date` keyword is a better way to include a date constant; for instance, it uses the ISO 8601 standard date format.

Comment: Hmm, im getting a missing keyword on where clause. no i need a left join instead of just join?